# python bitwise operations on C data types?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, ctypes

Is it possible to do bitwise operations on C data types in Python?

```
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:13:53) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ctypes import c_uint8
>>> foo = c_uint8(4)
>>> foo << 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'c_ubyte' and 'int'
>>>
```

Comment: perhaps try int(foo) << 1. Or cast `1` into a `c_ubyte

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `foo.value << 1`

or to update foo,

```
foo.value <<= 1
```

Answer (score 4):

This works, but it isn't done at the C level:

```
foo.value << 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from ctypes import c_uint8
foo = c_uint8(4)
print foo.value << 1
```

will print `8` as you want. To change `foo`, use

```
foo.value <<= 1
```